# Sum of rows sums for gruped variables

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to create function with to variables `df` and `number`

```
df <- data.frame(a=c(4,4,3,3,3,2,4,4,5,5), 
                 b=c(3,4,1,4,5,2,1,5,1,2), 
                 c=c(5,3,2,1,2,4,5,3,3,3), 
                 d=c(5,4,1,5,4,3,1,2,5,4), 
                 grp=c(4,2,2,1,1,4,4,1,4,4))
df %>% group_by(grp) %>% summarise_each(funs(sum)) #only to see sums for grp variable!
number <-c(1,2,3,4)
```

I used `group_by` function to see what are the sums for each column in `df` data frame. I would like to compare values in `grp` colum with these in `number` vector and create new data frame with:

1. values in row with `number` value 1 are equal to those in row `grp` 1 grouped by 'grp'
2. values in row with `number` value 2 are equal to sum of those in row `grp` 1 and `grp` 2 grouped by 'grp'
3. values in row with `number` value 3 are equal to sum of those in row `grp` 1 and `grp` 2 (because there is no `grp` 3) grouped by 'grp'
4. values in row with `number` value 4 are equal to sum of those in row `grp` 1, `grp` 2 and `grp` 4 grouped by 'grp'

Final result:

```
new <- data.frame(grp=number,
                 a=c(10,17,17,37), 
                 b=c(14,19,19,28), 
                 c=c(6,11,11,31), 
                 d=c(11,16,16,34) 
                 )

new
#  grp  a  b  c  d
#1   1 10 14  6 11
#2   2 17 19 11 16
#3   3 17 19 11 16
#4   4 37 28 31 34
```

Comment: Who did you get `grp` 3 in final dataset when you didn't have a group 3 in the first place?

Comment: @useR `grp` 3 was taken from `number` vector

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems you need `cumsum` on all the other columns except for `grp`; To fill in the missing `grp`, you can use *tidyr::complete* with `number`:

```
library(dplyr); library(tidyr)

df %>% 
    group_by(grp) %>% 
    summarise_all(sum) %>% 
    complete(grp = number) %>% 
    mutate_at(vars(-one_of('grp')), ~ cumsum(coalesce(., 0)))

# A tibble: 4 x 5
#    grp     a     b     c     d
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1    10    14     6    11
#2     2    17    19    11    16
#3     3    17    19    11    16
#4     4    37    28    31    34
```

Comment: Hi, I am having an error `Error in UseMethod("as.fun_list") : 
  no applicable method for 'as.fun_list' applied to an object of class "formula"`. Do you know what can couse it?

Comment: Try replace `~` with `funs`. `mutate_at(vars(-one_of('grp')), funs(cumsum(coalesce(., 0))))`, I am using a `tidyverse` syntax for a function which might not be compatible with your library versions.